# How to save created pdf file to specific foler created in jsp project

Tags: jsp

I have created a PDF using itext and want to save in folder created under directory-/web/HR/employee_report. My problem is finding the path.

I get the path through:

```
ServletContext servletContext = getServletContext();

String contextPath = servletContext.getRealPath("File.separator");
```

and store the path in a string as:

```
 String FILE = contextPath+"\\HR\\employee_report\\file1.pdf";
```

But result is zero;
however, when I manually change path as

`String FILE = "F:\\\SFC\\\web\\\HR\\\employee_report\\\file1.pdf";`

then it is working.

Comment: If you run this in IDE like Eclipse , this problem is due to eclipse so go and check file manually in disk , File will be there.But due to some path problem file will not be shown.because here file will be stored in path like this "E:\Leo-Softwares\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\TestWeb" but in realtime application it will work .

Comment: no problem with finding path in windows environment "." folders are hidden.